# HTML5 video does not hide controls in fullscreen mode in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

In Google chrome browser when I change to full screen mod standard controls showing when mouse move. Also always enabled function show control on right click menu (only on full screen), I can't disabled it. So I tray this js functions but they not working. 
JS:

```
$('.gp_nav_fc').click(function() {
    elem = $('#bcVideo')[0];
    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
        elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
         elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }
    $('.gp_buttons').attr('class', 'gp_buttons fullscreen');
        elem.controls = false;
        $('#bcVideo')[0].removeAttribute("controls");
        $('#bcVideo').controls = false;
});
```

HTML:

```
<video id="bcVideo" src="anotherhost.com/video.mp4" style="position: absolute;" poster="poster.gif"></video>
```

I change src course it very long, but video getting from another domain.

Comment: Can you show some code (more than the two lines)?

Comment: Looks like the disabling of the controls in fullscreen gets overridden.

Comment: It looks like this property blocked in full screen by chrome. So in ff and chrome normal mod (not full screen) everything good.

Comment: It looks like you have to create your own controls if you want them to be hidden in fullscreen.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So I find answer for this question.

In css need to add next rule:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls {
  display:none !important;
}
```

more information on link: http://css-tricks.com/custom-controls-in-html5-video-full-screen/