# Fullscreen mode in Google Chrome does not work

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video, fullscreen

By clicking on my fullscreen button the video stretches to it's original size but is not displayed in fullscreen. But I dont want black bars at more than two sides. There are no css attributes used that could explain that. To set the video attributes to `width: 100%;` and `height: 100%;` or auto didn't help. Fullscreen works perfectly in Firefox but not Chrome. I enter fullscreen mode with this code:

```
$('.fullscreen-btn').click(function () {
            if (movie[0].requestFullscreen) {
              movie[0].requestFullscreen();
            } else if (movie[0].mozRequestFullScreen) {
                movie[0].mozRequestFullScreen();               

            } else if (movie[0].webkitRequestFullscreen) {
              movie[0].webkitRequestFullscreen();
            }
            ...
});
```

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: There's really little code to help you there... Got any jFiddle? Page's HTML?

Comment: Thx and sorry, can't do that. I figured out that it works if the default controls are enabled. But i wanna use my own controls. It even works when you click on the fullscreen button (resizes to video size), the smallscreen button (resizes to player size) and click on the fullscreen button again (then it resizes to fullscreen). It's strange. But there seem to be more problems. Sometimes Chrome crashes after closing the video.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution! The problem was a conflict between the default html5 video controls of Chrome an my customized controls. Thanks to an answer of this question: [hide video controls in fullscreen mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270894/html5-video-does-not-hide-controls-in-fullscreen-mode-in-chrome) 
I found out that the problem is resolved by using the css rule:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls {
  display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: May i know if making html5 player fullscreen via javascript on android chrome is possible?i tested it and works on iphone but not on android chrome!do you know why?

Comment: Hey! I think "dubbed Immersive mode" (since Android 4.4) is the big magic word. But I don't have any experience with it but I guess you'll find something when you google it ;)

Comment: @sharvan: Worked at that time. If you need help please send a fiddle! Maybe this link could help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/cross_browser_video_player It's not that old and the css rule seemed to work there.