# Disable play/pause/full screen for HTML5 <video> on click for YouTube

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, html5-video

Is there a way for us to disable the "play/pause/full screen on click" functionality for a HTML5 video through javascript and later put it back when we need it again?

Comment: This should help you solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14101874/how-to-disable-default-controls-on-a-full-screen-html5-video

Comment: maybe, but there is no such functionality for an HTML5 video. you must have some custom JS also going, and how you adjust that is impossible to guess without more info.

Comment: @dandavis Oh I'm working on a chrome extension for YouTube. Do you know what they're using?

Comment: no, i don't know, you need to dig through the code you're using, including youtube's. i am sure the youtube code is a minified mess, so that might be hard. but, i do know that a transparent div placed over the video will stop any and all clicks...

Comment: Could you explain how this question relates to YouTube? Is it about a YouTube video embedded in your website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why `<video>` doesn't honor `event.preventDefault();`

The way I go around this is pretty hacky. I just override the click and dblclick events of the parent div to solve my problem since I only want to prevent pause/play/full screen.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you can disable them but you can remove them using css.

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button, video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button, video::-webkit-media-controls-pausebutton {
    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4ce23z2a/

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer but just removing the controls doesn't solve my problem here since you could still click on the videos to control it.

Answer (score 0):

The below line can solve the purpose.

```
video.removeAttribute('controls');
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.