# User agent stylesheet blocked displaying audio after innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to do this:

```
document.getElementById(showPlayerId).innerHTML = '<audio id="audioPlayer" class="volume-on" onended="audioEnded()"> <source id="mp3Audio" src="#" type="audio/mp3"> Not supported. </audio>';
```

But that element is not showing because of user agent stylesheet:

```
audio:not([controls]) {
    display: none;
}
```

Does somebody have some suggestion how to fix that? That player is custom-made, I do not want default control buttons.

If I add `controls="controls"` it works, but I do not want that.

Comment: What do you expect to see when controls are disabled?

Comment: Just audio timer and bar. Do you know what is a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Turning controls off on an HTML `audio` or `video` element hides *all* of the controls which would normally appear on the element, including the seek bar and time. A `video` element with no controls just shows the video content, and an `audio` element with no controls is invisible.

If you want a custom set of controls on an `audio` or `video` element, you will need to construct *all* of the controls yourself. ([There are ways to hide specific controls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28389433/149341), but they are not portable across browsers, as the shadow DOM of the controls is not designed the same way on all browsers.)